# Drawing random numbers returns only integers

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, poisson

I am probably missing an important point on statistics or numpy/scipy.
I want to generate random numbers with poissonian statistics, whose expected value is `a decimal less than 1`, e.g., `lambda = 0.6`.
When I pythonize this:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import poisson
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lambda = 0.6
>>> poisson.rvs(lambda, size=10)
>>> print r
[2 2 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 2 ]
```

Trying

```
>>> r = np.real(poisson.rvs(lambda, size=10))
```

Gives the same result.

Why there are no decimals between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: @Ffisegydd is correct about the Poisson distribution. As an aside, since you already have `numpy` imported, you don't need `scipy.stats` too, you can just use `np.random.poisson(lambda, 10)`. Also don't use `lambda` as a variable name, that is a keyword in Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Poisson distribution is a [discrete probability distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonDistribution.html), meaning that you can only get integer variates, not decimal.

*Note: this doesn't mean the probability P associated with a particular variate is integer, that can be a decimal, just the individual variates themselves must be integer.*

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any alternative to get decimal variates with Poissonian (or Poissonian-like) distribution?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. [This pdf](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_039_2013/137_39.pdf) may be of interest to you, but the maths is pretty hefty.

Answer (score 2):

Poisson is not **continuous** probability distribution, so this is **expected behavior**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Furthermore do not call your variables **lambda**, this is an important Python operator